# EF6 - TPC inheritance fails when abstract base class has foreign key for other entity

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, orm, entity-framework-6

Thank you very much in advance,

I have an abstract class called `Person` which has a foreign key for the`City` table.

```
public abstract class Person
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("id")]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    [Column("city")]
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("CityId")]
    public City City
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

    [Table("cities", Schema = "public")]
    [Serializable]
    public class City 
    {
        public City()
        {
        }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }

        [Column("name")]
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }
```

And later I have my `Customer` class that inherits from`Person`:

```
public class Customer:Person
{
    [Column("cpfcnpj")]
    public String CpfCnpj { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm mapping the `TPC (Type per Concrete)` inheritance as follows in my context class:

```
public class MyContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    public MyContext():base("MyConnection")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;   
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("customers", "public");
        });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

When I try to pick up my `customers` I get the following error:

> Person: : The referenced EntitySet 'Person' for End 'Person' could not
>   be found in the containing EntityContainer.

The code used to select customers is the following:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
     //get error in this line
     var customers = context.People.OfType<Customer>().ToList();

    //...
}
```

**Note:** To test, I passed the `foreign key` properties for the `Customer` concrete class and executed perfectly.

Can someone help me? I really need to understand this situation.

Thanks.

Comment: That's unavoidable limitation of TPC. See [Inheritance with EF Code First: Part 3 – Table per Concrete Type (TPC)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines), in particular *Polymorphic Associations with TPC is Problematic* section, but here the problem is that there should be a single FK to `City`, but no single table where to put it. Consider switching to TPT or no EF inheritance at all.

Comment: Sorry, actually I was wrong. I've tried your model in EF6.2 and it works.

Comment: thanks, worked perfectly in version 6.2. I was with version 6.0 installed.

Comment: I have another problem, so when I have an IColection <OtherEntity> in my abstract class, which refers to a one-to-many mapping, it gives the following error: "Column OtherEntity_Id is not found".?

Comment: I guess this is the scenario described in *Polymorphic Associations with TPC is Problematic* from the link.